# How to search the multi column of database using gridview and textbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Means if i have two columns in database namely name & email

i wanna search the users or email by entering either name or email on textbox then after clicking the search button record will be displayed in gridview ?

can anybody tell me the select query for this ?

Example of this is www.google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following selects usernames or emails that contain the search term:

```
SELECT * 
FROM UsersTable
WHERE UserName LIKE '%' + @searchText + '%' 
   OR UserEmail LIKE '%' + @searchText + '%'
```